# How can I check if Bash POSIX Mode is enabled?

Tags: bash

[Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-POSIX-Mode):

> Starting Bash with the --posix command-line option or executing ‘set -o posix’ while Bash is running will cause Bash to conform more closely to the POSIX standard by changing the behavior to match that specified by POSIX in areas where the Bash default differs.

Comment: Note that the description given lies -- there are *absolutely* incompatibilities with the POSIX spec left with that mode enabled, most notably in the behavior of `echo` -- which only becomes compliant with the `xpg_echo` flag also enabled. (There are also a great many extensions that remain enabled, but those usually aren't incompatibilities as such, as they're specified with the intention that they don't conflict with standard-mandated behavior).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For interactive use,

```
set -o | grep posix
```

...will emit something like:

```
posix           off
```

For programmatic use, just enable or disable it (with `set -o posix` or `set +o posix` respectively) as suits your needs; there's little reason to ever check the prior value. That said, if you **really** want to, you can check `SHELLOPTS`:

```
case :$SHELLOPTS: in
  *:posix:*) echo "POSIX mode enabled" ;;
  *)         echo "POSIX mode not enabled" ;;
esac
```

Comment: `set -o | grep posix` works in my standard shell. But I'm debugging a script which reports SHELL=/bin/bash, yet posix is missing from the output of `set -o`. What could that mean?

Comment: @Rizzer `SHELL` doesn't tell you which shell is _currently running_; it only tells you which shell is the user's configured default. (The more reliable way to check if the current shell is bash is to `echo "$BASH_VERSION"`).